# ORM issue after upgrading to ColdFusion 2018 from version 11

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

We migrated from ColdFusion 11 to ColdFusion 2018 and now ORM is breaking the `EntitySave` method and we are getting below error message.

> Error Message - The root cause of this exception was: coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateSessionException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1.

We have 2 classes with one-to-many relationship like Email.cfc (parent) and EmailItems.cfc (child). When we try to save Email.cfc object the hibernate creates an UPDATE query for `EmailItems` as well and this is happening with ColdFusion 2018 only.

Here is the defined property in Email.cfc.

```
<cfproperty name="EmailItems" 
            lazy="true" 
            fieldtype="one-to-many" 
            inverse="true" 
            fkcolumn="EmailID" 
            cfc="EmailItem" 
            singularName="EmailItem" 
            type="struct" 
            structkeycolumn="EmailItemKey" 
            structkeytype="string" 
            cascade="none"
/>
```

We are using inverse and it still create an UPDATE query for child class 'EmailItems' which is the reason for failing `EntitySave(Email)`. Everything works fine with ColdFusion 11.

Comment: Two things come to mind. 1. Does it work without the foreign key 2. I wonder if Hibernate has cache that needs to be flushed.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It's not due to hibernate cache because my call is within CFTRANSACTION tag. Below is the code - <cfscript>
  transaction {
   arguments.email.setIsPersisted(true);
   EntitySave(arguments.email);
  }
 </cfscript>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the fix for this. It seems the `inverse="true"` properties doesn't work the same WITH cf2018 as it is working with CF2011.

After doing some research found that, by default a cascade property is added in `<cfproperty>` tag for one-to-many relationship whose value is UPDATE that means for any orphaned child object it is trying to update while this object doesn't exist at database level.

So, when adding `cascade="save-update"` in my `<cfproperty>` tag for on-to-many relationship, it fixes the problem because now it tries to INSERT instead of UPDATE for any orphaned child object.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. Thanks for coming back and posting your solution.